# Rough surface coated PEI textured build surface to fit Anycubic Kobra Max?

Tags: build-surface, anycubic-kobra-max

I have an Anycubic Kobra Max. It has a bed size of L430*W410.

I would like to print a rough surface as shown here:

[image: Photo of a coated PEI build plate with a printed model]

To do that, I need a coated PEI build plate, and I need to print the surface pointing towards the build plate.

The [coated PEI build plate that is shown in the photo](https://smile.amazon.de/BCZAMD-3D-Druckplattform-Doppelseitiges-Pulverbeschichtetes-3D-Druckerplattform-Gold/dp/B0B2RNRV5Q/ref=sr_1_38?crid=157VIYZ8GPGES&keywords=magnetisch%2Bdruckbett%2Btextur&qid=1662501414&sprefix=magnetisch%2Bdruckbett%2Btextur%2Caps%2C75&sr=8-38&th=1) was designed for an Ender 5.

I would like to know if somebody could point me to such a solution for a Kobra Max as I don't know what would be needed to "fix" it on the build plate.

Here is the full data for the product shown in the image just for clarification of what it shows:

- Ender 5 Plus 3D Printing Platform
- Double-Sided Powder Coated Without Magnetic Foot Base
- 3D Printing Build Surface 377x370 mm/14.8x14.5 inch
- Size: Only Double Powder Plate 377x370mm

Comment: From your description, it looks like you would need a magnetic sheet for the Y-axis carriage. Could you [edit] in a link to the product you are looking at purchasing so readers can help find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the PEI coated build surface is smaller than your actual build platform size you should be able to fit the build surface onto the build platform at the expense of a smaller print surface area. In the past I have secured sheets of glass with [Kapton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapton) tape (very thin high temperature resistant electronics tape), but glass is stiff and rigid. You might be able to use tape to tape the build surface corners to the build platform. However, from the website: `supplied without magnetic platform side B, the plates are coated on both sides so you can save one side for flawless parts while you need the other side. The performance may not be good without the soft magnetic base to maintain flatness. Do not recommend using them separately.`, so you need to get a magnetic platform to use this surface according to the seller.

This makes sense, as the sheet is thin, and some filaments warp (by shrinkage) considerably, the sheet may deform. You could try to use double sided high temperature tape, but that defies the the purpose of the build surface, you need to get it off easy and bend the surface to release the print. Therefore, a magnetic base is required.