# Are magnetic hotbed plates interchangable?

Tags: heated-bed, build-surface, anycubic-kobra-max

The Anycubic Kobra Max comes with a glass plate.

I need to use a textured PEI plate for my Kobra Max.

As I [understand it](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/19871), the PEI plate needs to be used on a magnetic bed plate.

Currently, there is no hotbed with a spring steel magnetic plate available for it yet.

I am still a complete newbie at plates.

Could I use an other magnetic plate for this, or do they have to specific to a certain printer (apart from the size of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the build surface is not the magnetic part, it is just a flexible steel PEI coated plate, so yes you could use a magnetic build platform sourced somewhere else.

> Currently, there is no hotbed with a spring steel magnetic plate available for it yet.

Actually there are solutions, note that complete build plate and surface systems are sold for the size of your printer, e.g. look into manufacturer [BuildTak](https://buildtak.eu/collections/removal-solutions/products/complete-buildtak-flexplate-system).